# When Qna maker is integrated with Power virtual agents, in power virtual agent follow-up prompts are not seen

Tags: integration, azure-qna-maker

I have a knowledge base in QnA maker, where in few answers i have follow-up prompts for multi-turn conversation. Those follow-up prompts are not seen in power virtual agent when integrated with qna maker. Any idea on how to get the follow-up prompts in PVA?

Comment: Not familiar with Power virtual agents, however I am with the QnA Maker multi-turn feature. Normally when we hear "I enabled QnA Multi-Turn in qnamaker.ai portal, but I don't see the multi-turn feature in my bot" it usually means **your bot still needs to integrate the code to actually create cards, and send the cards to the user**.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384642/azure-virtual-assistant-prompt-buttons/61393025#61393025, for a user who was having a similar issue. They only enabled multi-turn feature in the qnamaker API, but they didn't edit their bot to actually do anything with the multi-turn content returned through the API

Comment: @Subhashini harikrishnan Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @subhashini-harikrishnan did you solve this? Please update

Comment: @wallef  No, I don't think there is a way for this as of now !

Comment: Okay @subhashini-harikrishnan too bad. This a show stopper for us right now.
I hope they will add this feature. Thanks you :)